# Divide a Graphics Line into $i$ equal lengths

Tags: graphics, geometry, ticks

I have a line given by

```
line = Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {4, 4}}]]; 
 pointLabels = Graphics[
   {Text["A = (0,0)", {0.5, 0}], 
     Text["B = (4,4)", {4.5, 4}]}]; 
Show[line, pointLabels]
```

[image]

I want to divide it into `i+1` equal lengths, where `i` is a number of my choosing, and where each length along the line is marked by a tick.

It would also be great if the evaluation outputted a list of the coordinates for each `Tick`.

How?

**UPDATE:**

I should have been clear about this - I understand how to do this mathematically. I want to know how to put ticks on a line in such a way that it creates `i+1` equal divisions.

My comment about outputting the coordinates of the points was perhaps misleading.

Having said that, @halrutan's answer is the most comprehensive and I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The math behind this is not hard. If you have two points p1 and p2, you can reach every point on the line between them by choosing `0<=f<=1` and calculating

$$p_1 + f\cdot(p_2-p_1)$$

It's just linear interpolation. So when you divide the interval [0,1] into equally spaced points, you can easily create a table for all your points on the line.

[image]

The calculation of the points is done in the `pts = ...` part. The rest is only for display.

```
line = Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {4, 4}}]];
pointLabels = Graphics[{Text["A = (0,0)", {0.5, 0}], Text["B = (4,4)", {4.5, 4}]}];
gr = Show[line, pointLabels]

repl[n_ /; n > 1, num_] := Line[{p1_, p2_}] :> With[
   {
    pts = 
     Take[#, Min[num, Length[#]]] &@
      Table[p1 + i (p2 - p1), {i, 0, 1, 1.0/n}]
    },
   {Gray,
    Thickness[0.01],
    Line[Partition[pts, 2, 1]],
    Text[#, #, {-1.3, 1.3}] & /@ pts,
    Red,
    PointSize[0.02],
    Point[pts]
    }
   ]

Manipulate[
 gr /. repl[n, count],
 {n, 2, 10, 1},
 {count, 1, n + 1, 1}
 ]
```

Comment: Many thanks to both of you. I have updated my question in response to your answers. I wasn't clear that I understand the maths, I just need to know how to add the ticks.

Comment: "Lerping" + `Subdivide[]` (as in Okkes's answer) is nice, along with using dot products: `With[{p1 = {0, 0}, p2 = {4, 4}, n = 7}, Transpose[{1 - #, #} &[Subdivide[n]]].{p1, p2} // Composition[Through, {Line, Point}] // Graphics]` (@Richard, this is for you too)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a starting point.

```
x = y = Subdivide[4, 5];
pts = Transpose[{x, y}];  


Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, {4, 4}}], Text[#, # + {0.3, 0}] & /@ pts, Red,
  Point /@ pts}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

**Edit:**

```
dist = 0.1;
Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, {4, 4}}], Text[#, # + {0.5, 0}] & /@ pts, 
  Line[{{#[[1]], #[[2]] - dist}, {#[[1]], #[[2]] + dist}}] & /@ pts}]
```

[image]

Comment: I like your answer. Short and to the point. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
With[{pts = Subdivide[p1, p2, n]},
 Manipulate[
  Show[
   Graphics[{
     Black, AbsolutePointSize[4]
     , Black, Dashed, Line[{p1, p2}]
     , Red, Point@pts
     }
    , PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}}
    , Frame -> True
    ](* end Graphics *)
   ,
   ListPlot[
    Callout[#, Rationalize[#, 0.01]] & /@ pts
    ](* end ListPlot *)
   ],
  {{p1, {-4, 4}}, {-4, -4}, {4, 4}, Locator}
  , {{p2, {4, -4}}, {-4, -4}, {4, 4}, Locator}
  , {{n, 3}, 1, 7, 1}
  , TrackedSymbols :> All
  ] (* end Manipulate *)
 ](* end With *)
```

---

The rationalization of points is optional and is intended as a quick visual cue for establishing correctness for simple cases.

[image]